# SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

Beginner here again wanting advice. Trying to follow a tutorial for adding/edit/deleting data to/from the database.

However I'm getting the following error when trying to add a new title:

```
ERROR/Database(278): Error inserting Book_Title=testtitle Book_Author=testauthor

ERROR/Database(278): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

I suspect its a contraint on the ID, as the database is already created in a previous class file. However i'm not adept enough with Java to know how to fix it. Editing and Deleting data work fine.

Some code:

**DatabaseManager.class:**

```
public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);


        // ask the database object to insert the new data 
        try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {



        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // This string is used to create the database.  It should
            // be changed to suit your needs.
            String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                                        TABLE_NAME +
                                        " (" +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text" +
                                        ");";




            // execute the query string to the database.
            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);

        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // NOTHING TO DO HERE. THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATABASE VERSION.
            // OTHERWISE, YOU WOULD SPECIFIY HOW TO UPGRADE THE DATABASE.
        }
    } 
}
```

**AddData.class:**

```
private void addRow()
{
    try
    {
        // ask the database manager to add a row given the two strings
        db.addRow
        (

                textFieldOne.getText().toString(),
                textFieldTwo.getText().toString()

        );

        // request the table be updated
        updateTable();

        // remove all user input from the Activity
        emptyFormFields();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Add Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are told that you want to insert the record that cannot be inserted due to primary or foreign key/keys restrictions. Most likely you wanna insert the record with `ID` that has already been in the table.
There's no `autoincrement` keyword in SQLIte AFAIK, but there's an `_ID` attribute in any table, i recommend you to use it as primary key autoincrement instead of creating your own.

The exception occurs cause you don't insert your custom primary key and it's not autoincrement as you suppose.

Comment: I tried removing: TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," + However it didnt seem to make a difference, and the same error exists. How would I go about inserting the record with the ID that already exists in the table? (I've tried all sorts)

Comment: If the record already exists on the table, you update it not insert it.  Insert is for creating new entries.

Comment: The record does not already exist on the table. The database already exists (It is created class file previous to this one, on application launch)

Comment: Have you re-created the table after you deleted your custom primary key as you said?

Comment: Yes. I believe I may of solved part of the error anyway. As the dataform was "in-progress" I was trying to insert 2 fields of 6. When I inserted all 6 fields, the error went away (And I got a new error about cursors). So that seems to of been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete and recreate your database.

I do not see anything wrong in your code, I suspect a change in the table definition which makes database and code out of sync

(my code with sqlite does NOT end with semicolon ;, you may try this, too)